# Yargs - can I get "rest" arguments?

Tags: javascript, yargs

I need to process specific option, and pass all other arguments further as an array.

For example:

I call the script like this:
`node script.js --one 1 --two 2 --three 3`

```js
const args = yargs(argv).demandOption("one").string("one").argv;
console.log(args.one);

const rest = ???
console.log(rest);
```

Should write:

```
1
["--two", 2, "--three", 3]
```

Is this doable with yargs? Something like the `_` value, but `_` only contains non-option values so I can't use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to amazing yargs' test suite:
https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/main/test/yargs.cjs#L1841

I just need to configure the yargs to pass unknown options to `_` too:

```js
const args = yargs(argv)
    .parserConfiguration({'unknown-options-as-args': true})
    .demandOption("one")
    .string("one")
    .argv;
```